# Импорт модуля Node/JS, require/import, module/commonjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

Пытаюсь достучаться до импорта модулей.

Желание: использовать `require` и `import` независимо от типа модулей(module_es6/commonjs) без дополнительных библиотек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каталогах(картинка) `demo-*` - экспорт
В каталогах `import-as-*` - импорт того что в `demo-*`

Модули `*-commonjs` описаны в стиле `module.exports/require`
Модули `*-module` описаны в стиле `export/import`
Пример:

```
// "type": "commonjs"
module.exports = () => {
    return "i commonjs"
}
// "type": "module"
export default () => {
    return "i module"
}
```

В каждом `package.json` добавлено соответствующее свойство `"type": "module/commonjs"`
Пример:

```
{
    "name": "demo-module",
    "main": "./index.js",
    "type": "module"
}
```

Node(-v v12.13.0) запускается с флагом `--experimental-modules` и `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node`

С импортом из `import-as-module` все нормально, импортируется в том числе и модуль `demo-commonjs`.
А вот из `import-as-commonjs` не импортирует из `require('../demo-module')` ничего.

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]:  
Must use import to load ES Module: ...path.../demo-module/index.js
```

Как добиться желаемого результата?

> Ниже невыполнимый сниппет!!!

```js
// + ПРИМЕРЫ ЭКСПОРТА

// demo-commonjs | package.json->{name, main,"type": "commonjs"}
module.exports = () => {
    return "i commonjs"
}

// demo-module | package.json->"type": "module"
const CONST_MOD = 'CONST_MOD'
export { CONST_MOD }
export default () => {
    return "i module"
}


// + ПРИМЕРЫ ИМПОРТА

// import-as-module | package.json->"type": "module"
import CommonJS from '../demo-commonjs'
console.log(CommonJS())
import def, { CONST_MOD } from '../demo-module'
console.log(def())
console.log(CONST_MOD)

// import-as-commonjs | package.json->"type": "commonjs"
const CommonJS = require('../demo-commonjs')
console.log(CommonJS())
// ЗДЕСЬ ПОЛУЧАЮ ОШИБКУ
try {
    var CONST_MOD = require('../demo-module')
}
catch (error) {
    console.error(error) // Must use import to load ES Module:
}
console.log(CONST_MOD) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_code_require_code

> `require` **always** treats the files it references as CommonJS.

Так что ваше желание невыполнимо.

Comment: Так это не объект, с чего бы там spread был